# jQuery error [intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with

Tags: javascript, jquery

I working with jQuery UI and jquery.ui.touch-punch, When resizing the object, it gives me the following error:

*Note: The error appears when I test in chrome (PC) in mobile mode (Ctrl+Shift+M)

```
[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchend event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I don't understand what the error is, how do I fix it?

I have no experience with this error, where is the error?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I assume you've read this: https://www.uriports.com/blog/easy-fix-for-intervention-ignored-attempt-to-cancel-a-touchmove-event-with-cancelable-false/

Comment: @Kinglish with your link I no longer have the error, but the resizable object with jqueryUI no longer works resize in chrome mobile browser.